# Create global map variables

Tags: dictionary, global-variables, go

I need a little help regarding creating a global map variable in Go. What I have done is as follows:

```
package ...
import(
...
)
...
type ir_table struct{
    symbol      string
    value       string
}
var ir_MAP map[int]ir_table
```

Since I am not initializing the map, I am getting a nil pointer dereference error. What must I do to use this variable globally? Or, if this is not a correct way to do this, please guide me.

Comment: Initialize it? `var ir_MAP = make(map[int]ir_table)`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to initialize it with an empty map:

```
var ir_MAP = map[int]ir_table{}
```

or, as "the system" suggested:

```
var ir_MAP = make(map[int]ir_table)
```

The problem is that the zero value of a map is nil, and you can't add items to a nil map.

Comment: Why does this `ir_MAP := make(map[int]ir_table{})`? as global variable give Error: `non-declaration statement outside function body `

Comment: @overexchange, declaring variables with `:=` only works inside a function. Outside a function, you need to use `var`.

Comment: Yes, but what is the idea? for syntax change in usage of `:=` for global vs non-global?

Comment: All top-level declarations begin with a keyword that indicates the type of declaration. (`func`, `var`, `const`)

Answer (score 23):

You can directly initialize a map like this:

```
var Romans = map[byte]int{
    'I': 1,
    'V': 5,
    'X': 10,
    'L': 50,
    'C': 100,
    'D': 500,
    'M': 1000,
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You almost have it right.  You just haven't initialized your map yet.

Here's working code in [The Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4tL1Yff2LK).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ir_table struct{
    symbol      string
    value       string
}
// define global map; initialize as empty with the trailing {}
var ir_MAP = map[int]ir_table{}

func main() {
    ir_MAP[1] = ir_table{symbol:"x", value:"y"}
    TestGlobal()
}

func TestGlobal() {
    fmt.Printf("1 -> %v\n", ir_MAP[1])
}
```

Answer (score 9):

old topic, but the most elegant solution hasn't been mentioned.
This is quite useful in modules where it's not possible to assign values in the main function. init is executed only once so it saves a few CPU cycles every time the map would have to be initialized otherwise.

https://play.golang.org/p/XgC-SrV3Wig

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    globalMap = make(map[string]string)
)

func init() {
    globalMap["foo"] = "bar"
    globalMap["good"] = "stuff"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("globalMap:%#+v", globalMap)
}
```

Comment: But the `make`-based solution _was_ already mentioned, and the `init()` part is a special use case not asked for.